# Python sleep for a long time precision

Tags: python, sleep, long-integer

I see many questions about the precision of time.sleep() in miliseconds, but how does it perform, in lets say 3600 * 24 seconds ( a full day ) how precise would it be. Would it be offset by a few seconds or like a more significant ammount of time ? has anyone tested this on Linux or Windows ?

Comment: Its only as precise as your system's clock source.

Comment: if I made a sleep(3600) 24 times, would it be equal to sleep(3600 * 24) ?
(negecting the waking time of the thread)

Comment: Given that *"negecting [sic] the waking time of the thread"* is a ridiculous thing to do, what does it matter how precise it is? If you need to do something at a particular time, sleeping until that time isn't the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The precision would only be limited by :

- the accuracy of the system clock (it is a quartz so it should be much better than one second a day)
- [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) if your system is synchronized with an official source - but you would be unlucky : 27 leap seconds since 1972 ...
- the load of the system that could not restart immediately your task

So I cannot imagine how the precision could be worse than several seconds.